# Permission Set Assignment in Salesforce Einstein Analytics Error

Tags: einstein-analytics, permission-sets, dataflow

I created a Dataset in Einstein Analytics that simply gets data from **Permission Set Assignment**, nothing fancy.

While Running the Dataflow I am getting the below error:

> Something went wrong while executing the sfdcDigest_PermissionSetAssignment node: Internal Error. Contact support. (02K2v000000HoAZEA0_03C2v000000RfWHEA0)

Is there a specific reason why it is breaking or is it something am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't get any answer or responses, I went ahead and did some try. I was able to solve this issue. Below are the steps:

1. Goto **Data Manager**.
2. Click on **Connect**.
3. Search for the object for which you're facing the issue.
4. Click on the Down Arrow at the far right of the Object and click on **Disconnect Object**.

Just make sure that you're not using that Object in any of the Dataflows or it won't let you disconnect your object. Delete the Dataflows containing that object and try the process again.

Let me know if you guys still face this issue.